# How to set a date From one picker to another picker using Clean jQuery Date and Time Picker Plugin - datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

I am using two Date pickers. When I select a date from start-date picker. I will set it into end-date picker. But I tried. It did not set please help me.

```
$('#start-date').datetimepicker({
    onShow: function(ct){
        this.setOptions({
            minDate: new Date()
        });
    },
    timepicker: false,
    format: 'Y/m/d h:m A',
    datepicker: true,
    hours12:true,
    defaultSelect:true,
    hideIfNoPrevNext: true,
    minDate:false,
    onSelectDate: function(date) {
        var endDate_picker = $("#end-date");
        var minDate = moment(date,"Y/m/d h:m A");
        var endDate = moment(moment(minDate).toDate()).add('hours', 2);
        console.log('curr date :' + date);
        console.log('minDate :' + minDate);
        console.log('endDate : ' + endDate);

        console.log('moment : ' + moment(endDate_picker.val(),"Y/m/d h:m A").toDate());
        console.log('minDate.toDate() :' + minDate.toDate());

        if ((endDate_picker.val() == "")||  (moment(endDate_picker.val(),"Y/m/d h:m A").toDate()) < minDate.toDate()) {
            $('#end-date').datetimepicker('setDate', endDate.toDate());
            console.log('end date set :' + endDate.toDate());
        }                 
     }              
});
```

To set Date I use this code:

```
$('#end-date').datetimepicker('setDate', endDate.toDate());
```

Comment: @Monasha : Thanks for formatting my code.

Answer (score 1):

A few minor mistakes

> 1.Datetimepicker format uses `i` for minute not `m`
>
> 2.Moment.js `add()` syntax has [changed](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/)
>
> 3.`setDate` is an internal function in datetimepicker  not expose as a public method for setting date , for that use `value` option while initializing

```
$('#start-date').datetimepicker({
    onShow: function(ct){
        this.setOptions({
        minDate: new Date()
        });
    },
    timepicker: false,
    format: 'Y/m/d h:i A',
    datepicker: true,
    hours12:true,
    defaultSelect:true,
    hideIfNoPrevNext: true,
    minDate:false,
    onSelectDate: function(date) {
        var endDate_picker = $("#end-date");
        var minDate = moment(date,"Y/m/d h:m A");
        var endDate = moment(moment(minDate).toDate()).add(2,'hours');

        if ((endDate_picker.val() == "")||  (moment(endDate_picker.val(),"Y/m/d h:m A").toDate()) < minDate.toDate()) {
            $('#end-date').datetimepicker({value: endDate.toDate(),  format: 'Y/m/d h:i A'});
        }                 
    }              
});
```

Comment: U're Welcome ;)

Comment: $('#start-date').datepicker("getDate")